# Capybara find element value of aria-pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I would like to get the value of aria-pressed for the below code in capybara:

```
<button aria-pressed="true" class="btn btn-default active" data-active="true" data-toggle="button" id="grid-filter-invited-button" type="button">
  Invited
</button>
```

It's a button... when i click on it, its aria-pressed value toggles between true and false..I want the value of "aria-pressed". Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes have a [] method that returns attribute values.

`capybara_element['attribute_name']` allows accessing an element’s attributes in `Capybara`

```
aria-pressed = page.find('button#grid-filter-invited-button')['aria-pressed']
puts aria-pressed
#=> "true"
```

[Reading an element's attributes with Capybara](http://makandracards.com/makandra/30057-reading-an-element-s-attributes-with-capybara)

Comment: Even after clicking on the button and the value of aria-pressed = "false".. I'm getting page.find('button#grid-filter-invited-button')['aria-pressed'] has true

Comment: Can you please open the browser with Capybara's `save_and_open_page` and check weather it is change to `false` after clicking of the button.

Comment: How is the value of aria-pressed being changed?  Is it possible there is a delay between the press and the change, and you're running the find before the value has changed?

Comment: Also -- just to confirm that you are using a driver that supports javascript? and not just Capybaras default racktest driver

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check the value has changed. You should be able to assert this with an xpath expression. As it's a boolean, you could get a value by checking the results are `nil` or `empty`.

Something like:

```
page.all(
  :xpath,
  "//button[@id='grid-filter-invited-button'][@aria-pressed='true']"
)
```

or to expect it's been pressed:

```
expect(page).to have_selector(
  :xpath,
  "//button[@id='grid-filter-invited-button'][@aria-pressed='true']"
)
```

Also, take a look at this answer to a similar problem. You can also do it with a css selector: [RSpec + Capybara: How do I test a Bootstrap progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428141/rspec-capybara-how-do-i-test-a-bootstrap-progress-bar)